# SQL - Recursive Calculation Solution Required

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression

Good day,

Could someone please assist with how to achieve the below. So I need to take the first "Addition" which is the "Total_COB_Growth" + "Sum_of_Previous_Interest" where the "Sum_of_Previous_Interest" is dependent on the LAG of "Additions" if that makes sense. I can't get it right in SQL to have the previous value drag down on each consecutive line. (LAG() OVER (PARTITION BY etc.) returns zeros once it hits the 2/3 line:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsoaf.png)

My Table:

| UniqueKey | Pol_No | New_Total_Rate | Total_COB_Growth | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE000724266001001016 | 724266 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| DE000724266001001017 | 724266 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| DE000724266001001018 | 724266 | 8 | -9811.4 | 11 |
| DE000724266001001019 | 724266 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| DE000724266001001020 | 724266 | 10 | 0 | 1 |
| DE000724266001001021 | 724266 | 10 | 0 | 0 |

So the formulas in the green columns depend on each other and I am having a tough time figuring out how to code this in SQL.

First Formula (used in Excel):

```
Additions =H4 + ROUND(E4,0)
```

[Additions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ9ej.png)

Second Formula (used in Excel):

```
Previous_Interest =ROUNDDOWN(IF(C4=C3,G3*(1+D4/100)^(F4/12),0),0)
```

[Previous Interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF1wd.png)

What I want (Result after 2 excel formulas):

| UniqueKey | Pol_No | New_Total_Rate | Total_COB_Growth | Duration | Additions | Previous_Interest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE000724266001001016 | 724266 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| DE000724266001001017 | 724266 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| DE000724266001001018 | 724266 | 8 | -9811.4 | 11 | -9811 | 0 |
| DE000724266001001019 | 724266 | 8 | 0 | 0 | -9811 | -9811 |
| DE000724266001001020 | 724266 | 10 | 0 | 1 | -9889 | -9889 |
| DE000724266001001021 | 724266 | 10 | 0 | 0 | -9889 | -9889 |

My feeling is that this would be something achieved with CTE's but I have absolutely zero experience with those so really looking forward to solution for this.

Thanks in advance, this has been breaking me.

I've tried multiple subqueries to try and get the values copied over the partitioned lines but that does not help.

We use DBeaver on IBM i.

**This is what I have tried without success:**

```
WITH #cte AS (
SELECT 
    UNIQUEKEY, 
    POL_NO, 
    NEW_TOTAL_RATE, 
    TOTAL_COB_GROWTH, 
    DURATION,
    0 AS "Additions to date TF",
    0 AS "Sum of previous with interest",
    1 AS RowNum
FROM 
    QRYLIB.temp_Test
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    t.UNIQUEKEY, 
    t.POL_NO, 
    t.NEW_TOTAL_RATE, 
    t.TOTAL_COB_GROWTH, 
    t.DURATION,
    CASE 
        WHEN t.DURATION = 0 THEN 
            LAG(#cte."Sum of previous with interest", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY t.POL_NO ORDER BY t.UNIQUEKEY) + ROUND(t.TOTAL_COB_GROWTH, 0)
        ELSE 
            LAG(#cte."Sum of previous with interest", 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY t.POL_NO ORDER BY t.UNIQUEKEY)
    END AS "Additions to date TF",
    CASE 
        WHEN t.POL_NO = LAG(t.POL_NO, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY t.UNIQUEKEY) THEN 
            ROUND(LAG(#cte."Sum of previous with interest", 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY t.UNIQUEKEY) * POWER(1 + t.TOTAL_COB_GROWTH / 100, t.DURATION / 12), 0)
        ELSE 
            0
    END AS "Sum of previous with interest",
    #cte.RowNum + 1 AS RowNum
FROM 
    QRYLIB.temp_Test t
JOIN 
    #cte ON t.UNIQUEKEY = #cte.UNIQUEKEY + 1
)
SELECT 
    UNIQUEKEY, 
    POL_NO, 
    NEW_TOTAL_RATE, 
    TOTAL_COB_GROWTH, 
    DURATION,
    "Additions to date TF",
    "Sum of previous with interest"
FROM #cte
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY UNIQUEKEY;
```

**Error Received:**

SQL Error [42908]: [SQL0343] Column list not valid for table.

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Comment: Noted, thank you. First time posting on the site so still figuring out how it all works :).

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at the details of the [error](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_75/rzala/rzalaml.htm#messages__SQL0343)?

> Causes:
>
> - The column name list must be specified following the table name of the common table expression. &1 is the common table expression name.
> - The sequence column name and the set cycle column name cannot be referenced in the column list of the recursive common table
>   expression. &1 is the sequence column name or the set cycle column
>   name. For a CREATE INDEX with a RENAME clause:
> - The key column must be included in the rename column list.

Try naming the columns like so:

```
WITH #cte (uniquekey, pol_no, new_total_rate,total_cob_growth
           , duration, "Additions to date TF", "Sum of previous with interest"
           , rownum)
 AS (
SELECT 
    UNIQUEKEY, 
    POL_NO, 
    NEW_TOTAL_RATE, 
    TOTAL_COB_GROWTH, 
    DURATION,
    0 AS "Additions to date TF",
    0 AS "Sum of previous with interest",
    1 AS RowNum
FROM 
    QRYLIB.temp_Test
UNION ALL
<..snip...>
```

Comment: Thanks, changed as suggested above. Error has now changed to: SQL Error [42836]: [SQL0345] Recursive common table expression #CTE is not valid. 

I don't fully understand what the problem is as this is the first time ever trying the WITH RECURSIVE and to be honest I still don't fully understand how it all comes together, but I have noticed that when excluding the UNION ALL from the query I get a result, so I'm assuming something in the second part of the query causes the error. Sorry still a noob with this.

Comment: @VehanB Looking at your data...I don't think you need a recursive CTE...  LAG() should be enough all be itself.

Comment: Hi @Charles, ive tried the LAG approach but after the second row it starts lagging on the zero and does not give the required result. Maybe I’m using the partition wrong as I PARTITION BY Pol_No. If I can work around the CTE then I’m happy. Just been stuck in this for a couple of days XD